# Published ESRI layer scale dependency problems

Tags: arcgis-online

I have published a layer with 3 scale dependency settings so regardless of the scale one of the three layers should be visible at any one time.

When I view the layer using the "View In: ArcGIS JavaScript" link (from the ArcGIS REST Services Directory page) the layer works correctly, I zoom in and out and the features are rendered correctly.

When I then switch to my development map and include the layer in the map layers list and load the map up, the layer appears on the zoomed out scale fine (global view).  When I then zoom in past the threshold my layer completely disappears.  If I inspect the JavaScript I can navigate to map.layers.item[x] and the visible property is set to true but the layer simply does not render on the map.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

Layer caching is disabled.

The only difference I can see between the ArcGIS JavaScript view and my development map is the layer is a `FeatureLayer` in my dev configuration.

Comment: I've seen this once before. Layer draws fine at all scales in js viewer but disappear when zoomed in on my development web map. I noticed if I switched to a different browser it rendered correctly on the dev web map. No idea why this happened

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the scale dependency settings in your layer may not match the set LOD's you are using in your application.

You didn't say which API you are using.

4.x https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-support-LOD.html

3.x
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/lod-amd.html

You likely need to specify your LOD's if you have published any custom layers that don't match the standard LOD's defined.

Here is a link for how this would be done in 3.x
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/map_switch_layer_on_zoom.html

Comment: Thanks, yes API is 4.8.  Will look into this pronto!

Comment: I think the LODs are TileLayer specific but I'm using a FeatureLayer and no caching is enabled therefore LODs are not applicable? Is that right?

Comment: Yes that would be right then. In that case can you inspect the scale layer range that is returned by ArcGIS server for that layer?  See if it matches what's in the published feature layer.

Comment: If you have any special symbology in the layers, try publishing it with plain lines, points etc. I've seen custom symbology cause behavior like you describe.